# Singleton injected into a class - does it cause memory leak?

Tags: .net, vb.net, memory-leaks, singleton

I have a class MyClass that has a parameter of type MyThreadPool in the constructor (DI).

**MyThreadPool is a singleton**. The code is like the following:

```
Public Class MyClass
    Private _threadPool as MyThreadPool

    Public Sub New(threadPool as MyThreadPool)
        _threadPool = threadPool
    End Sub
End Class
```

Does holding the singleton MyThreadPool in a private field (_threadPool) in MyClass cause any instance of MyClass to stay in memory and become non collectable by the GC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because the reference is *from* the instance of `MyClass` *to* the instance of `MyThreadPool`. That means that the instance of `MyClass` would keep the instance of `MyThreadPool` alive, but not the other way round. The instance of `MyThreadPool` doesn't have a reference to the instance of `MyClass`, so it can't keep it alive.

Think of the garbage collector following references, exploring every object it can get to. If nothing has a reference to the instance of `MyClass`, it's eligible for garbage collection. You can't "get to" the instance of `MyClass` from `MyThreadPool`, so it's fine.

Comment: Thanks Jon... a related question is if MyClass has an Event that is handled by an event handler defined in a singleton (a global application level event handler), it won't cause memory leak, either, right?

Comment: @SamuelC: That's right. But again, the other way round would be a problem - subscribing to an event declared by a singleton (or a static event) can cause a leak.